# Как превратить WPF-приложение в консольное?

Tags: c#, wpf

Имеется WPF приложение. Написал уже очень много кода и не хотелось бы создавать консольное и переносить код туда. 
Можно ли как-то малой кровью превратить мое приложение в консольное? 
Тип вывода в свойствах проекта уже поменял. Теперь я так понимаю, нужно сменить точку входа, что бы окно не инициализировалось(Поправьте, не понял как написать слово(= ). 
Провобовал закоментировать строку :

```
InitializeComponent();
```

Но окно все равно появилось... Видимо не так я понимаю эту строку.

Comment: `Видимо не так я понимаю эту строку.` - да, это инициализация начинки окна, но само создание окна и его отображение в другом месте

Comment: Хм, вроде нормальный же вопрос, почему минусуете, товарищи?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Вам нужно открыть `App.xaml` и удалить установку `StartupUri`:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfTest.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

</Application>
```

Классы с окнами вы можете удалить вообще, а в файле `App.xaml.cs` переопределить метод `OnStartup` - это и будет ваша точка входа.

Ну и плюс, если вы хотите что-то выводить в консоль, то вам потребуется в свойствах проекта переключить его `Output type` в `Console Application`

---

Другой, более кардинальный способ (а может и более правильный) - создать в приложении еще один класс, например `Program` и добавить в него статический метод `Main`:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{

}
```

Затем в свойствах проекта изменить `Startup object` - указать этот класс.

В этом случае класс App тоже можно удалить - толку от него никакого не будет.

Comment: Класс! Спасибо!
Круто когда знаешь такие мелочи)

Comment: Эм, еще момент. Где теперь аргументы вызова искать?)

Comment: Все. туплю... В OnStartUp)

Comment: Да, в `StartupEventArgs.Args`. А вообще в любом месте программы вы можете получить параметры, переданные приложению вызвав метод `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()`. Обратите внимание, там в нулевом элементе массива идет сам путь вызова приложения, а параметры начинаются с индекса 1

Comment: @АлександрЛи, дополнил еще

Comment: Думаю второй вариант проще и правильнее. Т.к. по первому я столкнулся с проблемой - не удавалось закрыть приложение. 
Огромное вам спасибо!

Comment: @АлександрЛи, верно, нужно запускать вручную метод `Shutdown`

Comment: У меня метод Shutdown не сработал... Вообщем, 2 вариант - 100%)